# How to view a draft page in live view without publishing it

Tags: draft

I am creating a news item page for a future release but I can't figure out how to preview it in Live View without Enabling it.  Is there a way to view a page in progress without publishing it live?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible right out of the box. Make sure that you:

- Have the correct entry template set in the Section's settings
- Are using Craft's native `{{ entry }}` variables in the template.

It might be helpful if you posted your template code.